# Symfony: how to cascade undelete when using SoftDeleteable behavior extension?

Tags: symfony, restore, cascading-deletes

My entity `User` is related to other entities through OneToOne relations, and I'm cascading "delete" for all of them.

I'm using **SoftDeleteable behavior extension**, so when I remove a `User`, the entity is not actually removed from the database: the `deletedAt` field is simply set to DateTime(now), and so are all the `deletedAt` fields of the related entites.

Now, when I want to restore a User, I do as suggested in the docs:

```
$em->getFilters()->disable('soft-deleteable');
$user->setDeletedAt(null);
```

My problem is all the related entities stay deleted when I do this. Any idea how I could cascade the setDeleted(null) to all of them automatically?

Comment: Just to be sure: do you flush after setting deletedAt to null?

Answer (score 3):

Never used this extension but looking at open issues on GH repository I can see quite a few of them related to similar problems when working with associations:

- https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/656
- https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/1101
- https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/505

I'd try first to disable explicitly the filter for each related entity:

```
$filter = $em->getFilters()->enable('soft-deleteable');
$filter->disableForEntity('Entity\Article');
$filter->disableForEntity('Entity\SomeOtherEntity');
```

Otherwise I'd add a Listener (and bind it to one of the Doctrine events) to cascade the restore outside of `soft-deleteable`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to add a listener as you suggested, even if it doesn't look very easy.

Comment: Easier than you think! See docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: Yes, binding an event is easy, what I couldn't find out is how to get all "cascaded" entities. Something like $object->getCascadedRelations(). The info can certainly be found in the mapping but I don't know how to extract it.